# How to pass Docker Compose variables to Apache and PHP?

Tags: php, apache, docker-compose

Let's say I have a variable `TEST: test` passed in docker-compose.yml to a container. From the shell inside the container I can see by echoing that the variable really is passed. However, Apache (2.2) does not seem to receive it. For example, `PassEnv TEST` fails:

`Starting httpd: [Thu Nov 30 18:22:28 2017] [warn] PassEnv variable TEST was undefined`

Also `$_ENV["TEST"]` stays empty.

`mod_env` is loaded properly.

How do I get Apache to read the variables passed via docker-compose.yml, and how do I pass those to PHP?

What are the settings in Apache and PHP that block the passing of system environment variables?

I'm running CentOS 6.9, Apache 2.2, and PHP 5.3.3.